# Passing references to a C++ constructor and saving them to reference or non-reference types

Tags: c++, reference, constructor, pass-by-reference

I'd like to know if these are basically the same thing.

```
class ExampleClass {
    public:
        ExampleClass(Object& newObj) : obj(newObj) {}
    private:
        Object obj;
}

class ExampleClass2 {
    public:
        ExampleClass2(Object& newObj) : objReference(newObj) {}
    private:
        Object& objReference;
}
```

So would this not work with either of the classes?

```
ExampleClass* getExampleObject() {
    Object obj;
    return new ExampleClass(obj);
}

ExampleClass2* getExample2Object() {
    Object obj;
    return new ExampleClass2(obj);
}

void main() {
    ExampleClass* ec = getExampleObject();
    ExampleClass2* ec2 = getExample2Object();
    //Do something involving the member objects of ec and ec2
}
```

So are the member objects invalid after both getExampleObject methods? Doesn't the constructor of ExampleClass save a copy of the object referenced in its constructor?

Comment: your code does not compile, since you cannot assign pointers (as returned by getExampleObject and getExample2Object) to non-pointer variables ec and ec2.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, I forgot the *'s.

Answer (score 10):

`ExampleClass` is fine, as it takes a copy of the object referenced in its constructor argument.

`ExampleClass2` requires that the object referenced in its constructor argument exist for the lifetime of the `ExampleClass2` instance (as it stores a reference to the object, it does not copy it). If it does not, then the `ExampleClass2` instance will have a dangling reference as soon as the object to which it refers is destructed. This is the case with the `getExample2Object()` function as `obj` is destructed when `getExample2Object()` returns.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought but this made me doubt myself: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404305/c-reference-in-constructor)

Comment: @user1468729, in that question `myclass` has `std::string` member, not a reference to a `std::string`.

Comment: So does my first ExampleClass. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @user1468729, and your `ExampleClass` is fine. The code in the other question is legal, I think the question was asking _what_ if I stored reference. If you notice, the accepted (and correct) answer to that question also state to store a copy.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know if these are basically the same thing.

No, they are not. `Example`'s constructor takes an object reference and constructs a member object to using the object passed. This object is not a reference but a copy. In case of `Example2`, you are actually making `objReference` refer to object passed in ctor's parameter. You are good only as long as `newObj`'s lifetime.

The

```
Object obj;
return new ExampleClass2(obj);
```

is the classic case when it will fail. Once the function returns, you will have a dangling reference.